# Convert videos in ffmpeg filter_complex with different timebases to use xfade

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'd like to use ffmpeg's new [xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) filter to crossfade between two videos. In theory this is easy:

```
ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 \
  -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=duration=1:offset=5,format=yuv420p" \
  out.mp4
```

However, this fails with the error:

`First input link main timebase (1/1500) do not match the corresponding second input link xfade timebase (1/30000)`

Obviously these two videos do have different timebases. This is confirmed by the ffmpeg output:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 536 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1500 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
...
Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1117 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
```

I don't want to convert each video and save the results and *then* combine the two new temporary disk files. Is it possible to use `-filter_complex` to convert the videos before `xfade` so that they have the same timebase? So that I can run one command which takes any two videos and crossfades between them?

Attempting to set the timebase explicitly with the `settb` filter seems to work at first but then gets "stuck" on frame 3 and never makes any more progress:

```
$ ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]settb=1/AVTB[v0];[1]settb=1/AVTB[v1];[v0][v1]xfade=duration=1:offset=5,format=yuv420p" out.mp4
ffmpeg version N-53546-g5eb4405fc5-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 56.100 / 56. 56.100
  libavcodec     58. 97.100 / 58. 97.100
  libavformat    58. 49.100 / 58. 49.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'v1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomiso2
    creation_time   : 2014-08-20T20:47:56.000000Z
    encoder         : x264
  Duration: 00:00:12.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 538 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 536 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1500 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-08-20T20:47:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'v2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1286 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1117 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 159 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> settb (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> settb (graph 0)
  format (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #1:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x69aaac0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x69aaac0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x69aaac0] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x69aaac0] 264 - core 161 r3018 db0d417 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=15 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomiso2
    encoder         : Lavf58.49.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 15 fps, 15360 tbn, 15 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.97.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.97.100 aac
frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.94 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s
frame=    3 fps=3.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.24 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s
frame=    3 fps=2.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.24 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s
frame=    3 fps=1.5 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.24 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s
(and repeat this line forever)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the settb filter to set a common TB.

```
ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 \
  -filter_complex "[0]settb=AVTB[v0];[1]settb=AVTB[v1];\
                   [v0][v1]xfade=duration=1:offset=5,format=yuv420p" \
  out.mp4
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as I'd hoped: the encode gets to frame 3 and then repeats the same line over and over again forever: "frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.24 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=125".

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Excellent. That works, thank you! It doesn't offset the _sound_ from the videos, but that'll need to be done separately, of course!

Comment: Use the acrossfade filter for that. But trim the audio streams first as per the xfade offset.

Comment: What's the reason that the TB needs to be the same when they're being encoded (i.e. not concatted)?

Comment: I also got the same error for a differing frame rate which I resolved by adding the `fps` filter and setting it to 30/1. Is there an equivalent to AVTB for the fps filter? Unfortunately the xfade documentation makes no mention of any of these factors that need to be normalised before the crossfade can be applied.

Comment: What did you do to fix the hanging and repeating the same line forever? I have the same problem when using `settb=AVTB`